# Align the input with respect to screenwidth in vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

i have 4 inputs which have to be lined one after another and with the decrease in screenwidth the input box should move to next line and also width should be divided equally between 4 inputs and it  get adjusted respectively to the screenwidth. smaller the screen the inputs will start looking like one below the other..

sharing the sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-butterfly-kb318?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)this is what all i have tried..

edit: no harcoded width, it should be equally distrubuted to 4 inputs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a proper border-box, so your inputs will not overflow their container:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

After that, you can set `width: 25%` to input containers, add small horizontal paddings and remove margin-right. Later you can set `width` to `50%` and `100%` with the help of media queries for specific screen sizes:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .input-division {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .input-division {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```